# convert KOI8-R to UTF8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I need to convert a KOI8-R encoded string into plain UTF8

Comment: Note that converting between encoding is only guaranteed to work if you know 100% what the original encoding is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding):

```
$output = mb_convert_encoding($input, 'UTF-8', 'KOI8-R');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$output = iconv('KOI8-R', 'UTF-8', $input);
```

also worked :)

There is also the option for it to remove corrupt or unrecognized characters

```
iconv("KOI8-R", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text)
```

But you need iconv to be installed.